# Improve performance for function which counts common words

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this program, that uses Apache Spark to calculate the frequency of words.

I create an RDD with the key/value pairs(word=key, frequency=value). The dataset is distributed over worker nodes. The function frequentWordCount is executed at regular intervals. It selects strings from the files.
which are then converted into key-value-pairs and connected to the wordDataset-RDD. The words with a frequency of >50, are counted.

I was told that this approach is not performant. Can somebody tell me why and how I could improve this?

```
val sc = new SparkContext(...)
var wordDataset:RDD[(String, Int)] = sc.sequenceFile[String, Int](“…”).persist()

def frequentWordCount(fileName:String):Long = {
   val words = sc.sequenceFile[String](fileName)
   val joined = wordDataset.join(words.map(x=>(x,1)))
   joined.filter(x=>x._1._2>50).count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Approximately how many frequent words will you have? For a lot of reasonable tasks, I think it should be unexpectedly small - small enough to fit into each individual machine's memory. IIRC, words tend to obey a power law distribution, so  there shouldn't be that many "common" words. In that case, broadcasting a set of frequent words could be much faster than joining:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(...)
var commonWords: BroadCast[Set[String]] = sc.broadcast(sc.sequenceFile[String, Int](“…”).filter(_._2 > 50).collect().toSet)

def frequentWordCount(fileName:String):Long = {
   val words = sc.sequenceFile[String](fileName)
   words.filter(commonWords.value.contains).count
}
```

If you are calling `frequentWordCount` multiple times, it probably is also better to do it in just one RDD operation where your words are associated with a filename and then grouped and counted or something... specifics depend on how it's used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would anything change if the frequent word count adds up to 10k?

Comment: 10k words? That's peanuts. Say, 10 character per word on average, 20 bytes, plus whatever overhead, say, 50 bytes. That's like half a Meg ...

Comment: So, there would be no way?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of common words is small enough to fit into an in-memory `Set`, then what the other answer suggests (except, you need to `map(_._1)` there after `filter`.

Otherwise, the two things you could improve are (1) filter *before* join, you want to throw out extra data as soon as you can rather than unnecessarily scanning over it multiple times, and (2) as a general rule, you always want to join the larger dataset to the smaller one, not the other way around.

```
 sc.sequenceFile[String](fileName)
   .keyBy(identity)
   .join(wordDataset.filter(_._2 > 50))
   .count
```